# Identifying installation folders of installed applications in Windows

Tags: windows, installation, windows-explorer, uninstall

Is there a good way/application to get a good overview of which folders on a computer contains installed applications? The scenario could be something like this

> On a computer a bunch of application are installed in *C:\Program
>   Files*. On the same machine there is a folder named *D:\Program
>   Files*. I would like to quickly find out which, if any, installed
>   applications happen to be installed in *D:\Program Files*. We can not
>   assume that **all** applications located in the folder are installed
>   but might very well be remnants of some old Windows installation no
>   longer in use so the installed applications must somehow be scanned one by one and there installation folder marked somehow.

The rationale would be to be able to safely remove old installed applications not actually installed on this installation of Windows but that has somehow remained on disk.

Comment: The only way to determine if a program is installed is look at the registry, although, not all programs use the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the application appears in the Add/Remove Programs control panel, then you can find information about the apps installation in the sub-keys of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, including the property "InstallLocation". see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanx... With this information I was able to quickly put together a program that points out if a given folder contains installed applications or not and thus is safe to delete or not. I actually move it to quarantine to make sure the system isn't affected before deleting.